# Finding coconuts on the beach?

Tags: animal-crossing-city-folk

I'm playing `Animal Crossing: Let's Go To The City` on Wii, and after several days, I haven't found any coconut on the beach.

Shall I wait even more or are coconuts simply impossible to found on the beach on this Animal Crossing game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coconuts are still in City Folk and still wash up on the beach, but are pretty uncommon. You'll just have to check beaches until they appear, and make sure to pick up shells which could cover their spawn location.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about the spawn location thing. I guess I'll just keep waiting. Thanks a lot!